# I can't create edmx file with SQLite datasource

Tags: wpf, entity-framework, sqlite, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2015

I'm trying to create SQLite database with edmx file in my project. My problem is that I can not create Entity Data Model connected using SQLite datasource. There is no SQLite data source on the list. I have no idea what I'm doing wrong.

I analyzed two tutorials:

erikej.blogspot.com/2014/11/using-sqlite-with-entity-framework-6.html
vimeo.com/103372740

First of all, I installed SQLite from site with enabled Visual Studio integration and GAC registration (I have Visual Studio 2012 and 2015)

[Screen 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8KsPQ.png)

I installed Entity Framework nuget package and also connected SQLite libraries.

Screen 2

I created connection to my file database in Server Explorer. (There was an option to select SQLite as datasource)

Screen 3

I made "build" and restart Visual Studio.

Next I'm trying to add item > Entity Data Model to my project (EF Designer from database). When I try to create New connection, there is no SQLite.

Screen 4

Edit:
I have installed Entity Framework 6.1.3 Tools for VS 2012 and VS 2015. My Entity Framework NuGet package is also 6.1.3. I installed all updates for VS 2015 which I think they may be related.

Screen 5 (I updated Screen 1 file)

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Did you install the latest ef tools or the latest vs update?

Comment: At the beginning I installed the wrong version of SQLite and reinstall it several times. Finally, reinstall of Visual Studio helped.